# Change papersize of selected slides in beamer

Tags: beamer, geometry

Is it possible to change the paper size of some frames in beamer? I know you can change the global paper size using `\geometry{paperwidth=,paperheight=}` in the preamble, but assuming you want to change the size for one or a couple of slides only, how would you do that? The above command only works in the preamble.

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to change the slide size and not, say, resize the image to fit on the current slide size. Wouldn't that be a better option? Any slide resizing is going to get scaled back to screen size for presentation.

Comment: You can change `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` between frames, which should change the "paper size". However, it will only produce a regular-sized `frame` on a larger page size. *So* many other things have to be adjusted as well to yield a correct result. Why do you want this? What about the suggestion to reduce the size of the components (scale) themselves? You can also use the zoom feature of [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)...

Comment: I have the same question, not to fit an image but to resize beamer's slide size. I want it to be 13cm width and 10cm height. I used `\geometry{paperwidth=13cm}` in the preambule and worked, but not the same for `paperheight`.

Comment: @hkviktor I think that's a different question. If you want a different size for all slides, take a look at Beamer's documentation: it tells you how to do this. Beamer already loads `geometry` so some care is needed to ensure that your settings override the defaults correctly. Geometry is a bit weird and doesn't always behave as you think it should. (How I think it should, at least.)

Answer (score 6):

Broadly 'no'. You can use `\newgeometry` between frames

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some text}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\newgeometry{a4paper}

\begin{frame}{Some text}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but `beamer` does not 'know' about this and frame decoration will end up in the wrong place. Moreover, given the target of `beamer` (making presentation slides) it's hard to see how such a change can be meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

A very dirty hack could be to manipulate `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`, as [suggested by Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134876/change-papersize-of-selected-slides-in-beamer/283552#comment317419_134876).

However this does not adjust things like the `\textwidth` - a quick workaround for this is to place the frame content into minipages of appropriate widths.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\pdfpagewidth 21cm
\pdfpageheight 29.7cm

\begin{frame}[plain]
\vskip1cm
\begin{minipage}{19cm}
\lipsum
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\pdfpagewidth \beamer@paperwidth
\pdfpageheight \beamer@paperheight
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you disable the control tools on the second page? Thread attempt here about the topic https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385255/13173